# Searching for electronic spectroscopy reference book

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I'm looking for a reference book that will help me describe UV-VIS spectra of organic compounds in terms of Q band, MLCT band, Soret band, and so on. Is something like that available?

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick note: the terms you are using in your question are very specific, MLCT is used in multiple places in coordination chemistry whereas Q and Soret bands are (if I recall right) specific to porphyrin metal complexes. So you might be looking for introductory coordination chemistry textbooks here, not really organic chemistry.

Comment: @Szgoger Oh, great! Thanks for suggestion. Any recommended books on that?